# Extract data from form and add to database using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to simply display usernames and age on the webpage using Express Node.js and Mongoose/

The view should get updated on the left while the form is at the right. Refer [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kifk0.jpg) image.

Below is my **users.js** (/users route) followed by **html** of the form.

Bodyparser has been included in **app.js** of this application.
On clicking submit, 404 not found is thrown.

[Refer this error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L9rq.jpg)

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('userview');
});


router.post('#', function(req, res, next) {
    
    //User is the model created in app.js of this project
    var newUser = userModel({
          name:req.body.name,
          age: req.body.age         
    });
    
    console.log(newUser);
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('User created!');
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
 <form method="post">
                     Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                     Age:
                    <input type="number" name="age"><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Here is my **app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var applist = require('./routes/applist');

var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var app = express();



//set database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users');
mongoose.connection.on('error',function(){
   console.log('MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure that MongoDB is running');
    process.exit(1);
});
mongoose.connection.once('open',function(callback){
   console.log('Connected to Database');
   
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{type:String,uppercase:true},
   age:Number
},{collection:'userlist'});

//make model
var userModel = mongoose.model('userModel',userSchema);

app.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  userModel.find({},function(err,userModel){
      res.render('userview',{userlist:userModel});
  })
});

module.exports = userModel;



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**userModel** is present in app.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the view change

> name = "fullname" to name="name"

**userview**

```
<form method="post">
        Name <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        Age<input type="number" name="age"><br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: There might be the typo. Can u share the server.js and UserModel file too.

Comment: I think u forgot to add  `app.use('/users', users);`

Comment: Checked that too

Comment: Here is the solution for your problem  [Solution](https://gist.github.com/ShahrukhKumar/ffb56bc35789101690c9958219b32c4a)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to use `req.body` you need to use `body-parser` or `busboy`, `connect-busboy`, `multiparty`, `connect-multiparty`, `formidable`, `multer` etc. - see:

- https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Also, what is this route supposed to be:

```
router.post('#', function(req, res, next) {
```

This character is not valid in the URL path amd needs to be URL-encoded on the client side to work. Are you sure that this is the route your need?

If you are thinking about the fragment part of the URL (as in `http://host/path#fragment`) then it is not sent during the HTTP request at all. See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Hi i did include it in the same file , still doesn't work.

Comment: its supposed to be /users and not #. Is there an issue with mongoose based logic?